# Django - why cant i retrieve user name?

Tags: python, django

When i log in an user, and attempt to retrieve the username or any details i get the below error. Not sure what it really does mean?

```
def loginview(request):

    message=[]
    if request.method=='POST':

        if Loginform(request.POST).is_valid():
            login_form=Loginform(request.POST)
            loginuser=authenticate(username=request.POST['email'],password=request.POST['password'])

            if loginuser is not None:
                login(request,loginuser)
                print("attempted log in")
                uname=User.username
                print(User.get_full_name)

                return render(request,'payrequest/templates/landing.html',{'landing_content':'Well done, you are loged in as'+ str(User.get_username)})
            else:
                return render(request,'payrequest/templates/landing.html',{'landing_content':'Incorrect details, try again.','okurl':'login'})
        else:
            message.append("We had some difficulties processing your request, please try again. If the issue persists please contact the systems team.")
            return render(request,'payrequest/templates/landing.html',{'landing_content':'invalid data','okurl':'login'})

    else:
        login_form=Loginform()
        return render(request,'payrequest/templates/login.html',{'form':login_form})
```

Console prints:
`<function AbstractUser.get_full_name at 0x04560BB0>`

Comment: You forgot the `()` to call the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is `User` in your context, but methods (that's a model method, not a property) in Python code should be called with `()` like `user.get_full_name()`.

In Django templates you can skip it and the templates engine does it instead of you under the hood :)

Usually words starting with upper-cased letter mean Class names, not objects. So normally `User` is a `User` model class but `user` is a `User` model instance which you created or retrieved from the DB (example, `user = User.objects.get(pk=1)`).

Comment: thank you, i figured out after all that by doing this below did the trick. :)

Comment: user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    print(user)

Comment: anyway there `user.get_full_name` is a method and you can call it like `user.get_full_name()` on the `user` model object you've retrieved from the DB

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use the two following lines code replacing yours.

```
uname=loginuser.username
print(loginuser.get_full_name)
```

Comment: you are going to print the same output as OP has